# Results pane for Kotlin playground just like Xcode playground?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I really like using the results pane (right side panel) in Xcode playground for debugging some number crunching. I'm now working on a Kotlin project and the online playground does not have a results pane that reads out results as the program executes.

Is there a way to do this in Android Studio or is there an alternative to the online Kotlin playground that does?

[Kotlin Playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS40LjEwIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsImpzQ29kZSI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiaW1wb3J0IGtvdGxpbi5tYXRoLmFic1xuXG4vKipcbiAqIEBhdXRob3IgYW1pbm9ncmFwaHlcbiAqL1xuXG5mdW4gbWFpbihhcmdzIDogQXJyYXk8U3RyaW5nPil7XG4gICAgXG5cbiAgICAgICAgXG59In0=)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just found what I was looking for:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/quick-run.html#scratches-and-worksheets

Called scratches in Android Studio.

To create a Kotlin scratch, click **File | New | Scratch file** and select the Kotlin type.